# PHP: Parse error: on line 182

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I'm having this annoying error I can't seem to fix... Line 182 is

```
alert('Successfully Updated');
```

In context the code looks like this,

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
    echo '<script type = "text/javascript" >

    alert('Successfully Updated');
    window.location.href='contact.html';
    </script>';

} else {
    echo 'An unexpected error has occurred.';
}
```

Can anybody spot the error??

Comment: You're not properly escaping your quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the syntax highlighter clearly shows you have a quoting issue:

```
echo '<script type = "text/javascript" >

            alert('Successfully Updated');
            window.location.href='contact.html';
            </script>';
```

should be (or could be, as there are several fixes for this)

```
echo '<script type = "text/javascript" >

            alert("Successfully Updated");
            window.location.href="contact.html";
            </script>';
```

---

You're using single quotes (`'`) to mean two different things:

1. The boundaries of the string that PHP echoes, and
2. The boundaries of JavaScript strings embedded in HTML embedded in PHP.

PHP only knows about (1) so thinks that the string you want to echo ends immediately after `alert(`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 

    echo '<script type = "text/javascript" >
        alert(\'Successfully Updated\');
        window.location.href=\'contact.html\';
    </script>';

} else {
    echo 'An unexpected error has occurred.';
}
```